# Gimp - Average HSV values of selection

Tags: gimp

I want GIMP to calculate the average Hue, Saturation, and Value of a selection.

I could color pick several pixels from the desired area and [read off the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm0sx.jpg) from the *FG/BG Colour* tab. This would be wildly inefficient; I have to do around 100 of these.

Preferably, it would be automagic -- Reading off average RGB values and converting them to HSV would be acceptable, albeit suboptimal.

Comment: This probably should be tagged [tag:hsv] but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: Given the fact that there are `0` questions with that tag, I wouldn't do it, anyway - HSV is part of image manipulation and not a topic that [raises that many questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=HSV). However, the proper place to debate this would certainly be [meta](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Gimp. Science experiment involving colour. Feel free to migrate to superuser if it belongs better there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you want to do but close:

In Gimp 2.10,

- open the Histogram dialog (`Windows>Dockable dialog>Histogram`)
- set it to `Luminance`
- make a selection, and check the `Average` and `Median` values at the bottom of the dialog.

Otherwise:

- Install the [`ofn-average-fill` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)
- Make your selections, and call the script (`Edit>Fill with average color`)(you can assign it to a keyboard shortcut). It will replace the selection by its average.
- Use the Pointer dialog (`Windows>Dockable dialog>Pointer`) to read the value of the area.

Comment: Isn't luminance a separate thing from Saturation? (Or am I crazy?)

Comment: Yes, Luminance is only (close to) the "V" part of HSV; The second solution gives you more of HSV, but you don't get he median that is often useful. Also, the script would not be very difficult to modify to write the values to a file...

Comment: Ended up using a modified version of `ofn-average-fill`. Will clean it up and comment here at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

Second answer that could be faster:

1. `Color>Components>Decompose` and select the color model (HSV, HSL...). This gives you an image with 3 layers, that represent the H, S, and V components of the original image.
2. Start the Histogram dialog
3. Make your selection, and read the value at the bottom of the dialog. Select the H, S and V layers in the Layers list to display the histogram for each in turn.